# RTLD_NOW and dlopen not declared in this scope qt creator vulkan dlopen

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, g++, vulkan

I'm using g++ and qmake in qt creator to attempt to run a simple vulkan app opening the vulkan library, and I get the following errors:

> /home/cpnblank/Documents/vulkandev/qmakecpptest/main.cpp:12: error: ‘RTLD_NOW’ was not declared in this scope
>        void *vulkan_library = dlopen("libvulkan.so.1", RTLD_NOW);
>                                                        ^~~~~~~~
>
> /home/cpnblank/Documents/vulkandev/qmakecpptest/main.cpp:12: error: ‘dlopen’ was not declared in this scope
>        void *vulkan_library = dlopen("libvulkan.so.1", RTLD_NOW);
>                               ^~~~~~

```
#define VK_NOPROTOTYPES
#include <iostream>
#include "vulkan.h"
#include "vk_platform.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    #if defined __linux
    void *vulkan_library = dlopen("libvulkan.so.1", RTLD_NOW);
    #endif

    if (vulkan_library == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "could not connect";
    }

    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: You really need to spend several days in reading documentation, so leave your code for a few days and dive into domentation. You are missing a lot of basic knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Read documentation of [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and take the habit of reading the documentation of *every* function you are using.

You are missing a

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
```

and your link command should contain `-ldl`. Both are mentioned in that [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) `man` page (you could try `man dlopen` in your terminal to get it; see [man(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html)).

Notice that `dlopen` handles specially paths which don't contain `/`. You probably want to pass some *absolute* file path to `dlopen`. So your usage of `dlopen` is likely to fail, and you should handle that failure better (with [dlerror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlerror.3.html) and [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) which requires `<stdlib.h>`):

```
if (vulkan_library == nullptr) {
    std::cerr << "could not connect to libvulkan: " << dlerror() << std::endl;
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

BTW (since you `#include "vulkan.h"`), you probably don't need to `dlopen` the `libvulkan.so.1` but you should [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) your program to that library (probably by passing `-lvulkan` into some `g++` linking command). Read [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/), Drepper's [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf), the [documentation of `qmake`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-manual.html), of [GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html), how to [invoke the `g++` compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html), the documentation of the [GNU `ld` linker](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html), etc.

Be also aware of [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling), of [Vulkan Support in Qt](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/06/06/vulkan-support-qt-5-10-part-1/)